# Workflow getting associated for all the documents in the document set

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-2010, document-set

I created a workflow in a document library. I added a Document set with some documents and then associated a workflow for the document set after which the workflow gets associated for the document set as well as for the documents inside the document set. How do i avoid this. can any one ple help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question.
I've concluded that the workflow will parse everything in a DocSet..

This may be a work around: Have the workflow check the document content type and restrict it to just the DocSet type. The workflow still checks everything, but at least it only does stuff to the DocSet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a site collection reusable workflow, not a list workflow, google it, pretty lots of documentation in how to do it.